# How to validate the header of token for JSON?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use token in my search function. How to check the token is correct or not? If token correct then retrieve body to request the server. If wrong then just return the error message.

Request JSON

```
{ 
"header": { 
"Token": "558fedce-a84e-4a9a-8698-5cd27d5af3ed"
},
"body": { 
"WarehouseCode": "W001", 
"CompanyCode": "C001"
}
}
```

For example my token is 558fedce-a84e-4a9a-8698-5cd27d5af3ed so if correct then get the body part and serialize to request the server.

Comment: what have you try so far?

Comment: @vasily.sib I have tried to use this as string to request the server is successful but I need do more detail.

Comment: Use request.Headers.TryGetValue("Token", out strVal);

Comment: @ZeeCode Sorry,I don't understand. Could you write any example because I still new in this.

Comment: @NgShiJuin, Do you want validate the token at server side? If So, you can use filters to validate.